# Total Paid amount is mismatch with captured amount in paypal order

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.4, paypal-payflow-pro, order-totals

I have some inconsistent orders having issue with total paid amount difference with captured amount for paypal payment orders. Here I have one example order having total paid $160.51 and captured amount is $159.41. capture amount is less than total paid where order contains bundle items one is simple product and other is digital product. And the difference amount $1.1 is shipping_tax_amount. How to debug Paypal total collections.

Comment: Can you provide more information? For example, what are your configurations right now, and how are you identifying the discrepancies? Any additional information you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: Set the PayPal payment method's debug mode as "yes" and check the requested amount in the log under var/log/payment.log